# Why is this command Navigation.PushModalSync giving this error: 'Navigation' does not contain a definition for 'PushModalAsync'?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, compilation

Is it missing a dependency?

This is the code:

```
if (item.Text == "Notify") //Record Audio
        {
            var detailPage = new NavigationPage(new AudioRecorder());
            
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(detailPage);
        }
```

AudioRecorder is defined under the Views Folder. When I first used the Navigation.PushModalSync command, it complained of Navigation and it suggested I include 'Android.Content.Res' after which it then started complaining of the PushModalSync property.

These are the libraries I am using on the page from where I want to invoke another page:

> Abuse_Alert.Models; Abuse_Alert.Views; Plugin.Media;
> Plugin.Media.Abstractions; System;  System.Collections.ObjectModel;
> System.Diagnostics; System.Threading.Tasks; Xamarin.Essentials;
> Xamarin.Forms; Plugin.AudioRecorder; AbuseAlert.Views;
> Android.Content.Res;

Comment: what is the type of `Navigation`?  What is the context - is this code contained in a Page, a VM, or what?

Comment: I wanted to make it a modal Navigation since the view would be recording and playing audio. I am calling it from a menu item that is tapped on. The AudioRecorder has been defined in its .xaml file and associated .xaml.cs file under the views folder. It has two buttons (record & play). I don't know how to define it properly under the ViewModels folder.

Comment: that does not answer any of the questions I asked you.  You can try using `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation` instead

Comment: Yes. it worked in the emulator. I was able to record for some seconds and then stopped recording. But, I didn't hear much from the playback. So, I want to deploy to my phone to test it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by Jason actually worked. He asked me to use App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.